# Fade or Cutout Render Mode, least performance expensive?

Tags: unity, shaders, textures, optimization, materials

I would like to optimize my WebGL Unity game, so I was wondering if I have a plane with a texture of say a mountain for background, what render mode for its material be least expensive? Fade or Cutout?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try and profile both?

Comment: I'm afraid the difference may be too insignificant to notice

Comment: In that case asking which one is better for optimizing doesn't hold a lot of value does it?

Comment: Still I'm tryin to do best I can, it's WebGL

Comment: All right, in that case, just to re-iterate: Use one, profile, use the other, profile, compare results and pick the *best* one.

Comment: Okay I'll try, you mean profiler results in rendering right?

Comment: I'm not familliar with Unity profiling details so I can't really say anything about that.

Comment: I don't know either of these render modes, I can only guess that cutout removes every transparent part, while fade actually applies the trabsparency, in this case, it depends on the amount of polygons you need to render. If you have a lot if polygons (more than 10) choose the cutout render mode, otherwise choose the fade one.